# resolving local network DNS query from hostname rather than IP

Tags: dhcp, internal-dns, dnsmasq

I have a bunch of Debian VMs running on a Debian host, they're all connected through an internal private network. One of said VMs has static IP set to 10.0.0.1 and acts as a DHCP/DNS server running `dnsmasq` serving IP addresses to every machine on the network.

Inside the same internal network there is another VMs running a self-hosted GitLab. I obviously can reach it when the browser is pointing to `http://hostname` or `http://hostname.mylocaldomain.lan`, but I would love to reach it from `gitlab.mylocaldomain.lan`.

I don't want to set static IPs for my VMs therefore I'm not able to add a line to the router's `/etc/hosts` resolving the address to the VM's IP, and honestly I would rather simply have `dnsmasq` handle it automatically. The following line in `/etc/hosts` doesn't work (duh):

`hostname    gitlab.mylocaldomain.tld`

Is there any way to instruct `dnsmasq` to "recursively" resolve the query (like `gitlab.mylocaldomain.tld` resolving to `hostname`, and then `hostname` resolving to the DHCP-leased IP)?

My last resort would be to give the VM a hostname `gitlab`, but I'd very much rather not because it looks awful and prone to additional complications (and configs) down the road.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `CNAME` resource records? ([RFC 1035, 3.3.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035#section-3.3.1))

Comment: No I did not, thank you very much for the pointer!